# How to give border to Clippath and fit text of dynamic length in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to achieve the design as in the image below:

[image]

I could achieve the output as shown in the image below:

[image]

As in the first image, there is border with all the text fitted inside it. The length and lines of text inside clip is dynamic and can be of anylength and line.

My Problem is the text does not get it inside the clippath. Also the border of clipath is not showing properly. I have implmented as follows:

```
ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 10,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                      return i % 2 == 0
                          ? Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 0, 0),
                              child: CustomPaint(
                                painter: ReceiverBubble(),
                                child: Container(
                                    width:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                    child: Expanded(
                                      
                                      child: Wrap(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            " One of the most common way to do this is, using paths. In this blog post, we will go through each function which in Path class and see how ... One of the most common way to do this is, using paths. In this blog post, we will go through each function which in Path class and see how ...,",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 18),
                                            softWrap: true,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )),
                              ),
                            )
                          : Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: CustomPaint(
                                painter: SenderBubble(),
                                child: Container(
                                    width:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                    child: Wrap(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          " One of the most common way to do this is, using paths. In this blog post, we will go through each function which in Path class and see how ... One of the most common way to do this is, using paths. In this blog post, we will go through each function which in Path class and see how ...,",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 18),
                                          softWrap: true,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                              ),
                            );
                    },
                  ),
```

Sender bubble

```
    class SenderBubble extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..color = Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5);
    Path path = Path();
```

Receiver Bubble

```
    class ReceiverBubble extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..color = Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5);
    Path path = Path();

    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height-size.height*0.2);
    path.lineTo(size.width-size.width*0.3,size.height-size.height*0.2);
    path.lineTo(size.width-size.width*0.2,size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width-size.width*0.2,0);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}

    
        path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
        path.lineTo(
            size.height - size.height * 0.8, size.height - size.height * 0.2);
        path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - size.height * 0.2);
        path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
        path.close();
    
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
      }
    
      @override
      bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
    }
```

Comment: make a custom `ShapeBorder`, not `CustomPainter` - that `ShapeBorder` can be used with `ShapeDecoration` or passed directly as `Material.shape` / `Card.shape`

Comment: can you explain with code example